# How to pass cell values of grid view to message box

Tags: c#, gridview

Can anyone help me out! I am  displaying role and eligibility records to the user in gridview when he clicks a button, In the gridview i generated "delete" button for every row. When the user clicks the delete i want to pass role and eligibility cell values to the Message box or a popup. 
(Iam using visualstudio 2010 and Dotnet 3.5)

My c# code:

```
protected void OnRowDelete_grid_admin(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    TableCell cell = grid_admin.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
    string CellValue = grid_admin.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    string CellValue2 = grid_admin.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Are you sure to delete' + CellValue + Cellvalue2)</script>");                    
}
```

Comment: Can you post your gridview ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code which I Executed! On the base of the answers suggested i have this code

```
protected void OnRowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
 {
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alertmessage", "javascript:alert('Are You sure to Delete EmpId:" + grid_admin.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text + " from the Role" + grid_admin.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Text +"')", true); 
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   TableCell cell = grid_admin.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];
   string CellValue= cell.Text;

   TableCell cell1 = grid_admin.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1];
   string CellValue2 = cell1.text; 

Response.Write("<script>alert('Are you sure to delete' + CellValue + Cellvalue2)</script>");
```

Comment: The code you have send is also working thank you! but how to have two buttons in the Alert

Comment: @Hearty Two buttons ? i am sorry but can you elaborate your requirement.Do you want user to select "YES" or "NO" for deleting cell values ?

Comment: Yes! I think I must Write Confirm instead of Alert

Comment: Here it's a pretty good example but in this case user is using `RowCommand` event to delete records . http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238122/Delete-Functionality-in-GridView-with-Confirmation

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string CellValue=grid_admin.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
```

Comment: I tried it but "CellValue" is null!Error " Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'CellValue' is undefined"

Comment: What Your error is Javascript error , Not a C# error !!! Run Chrome browser , then check it !!

Answer (score 0):

I think your delete-controll is a `LinkButton` ?
Then this may work:

```
LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)e.CommandSource;
GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;
Label lbl1 = gvr.FindControl("NAMEOFLABEL1") as Label;
Label lbl2 = gvr.FindControl("NAMEOFLABEL2") as Label;
Response.Write("<script>alert('Are you sure to delete' + lbl1.Text + lbl2.Text)</script>");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but iam not using any Controls(labels) in the gridview i want to get the cell values

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN LINK ON ROW DELETING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdeleting.aspx)

```
String value = gridViewID.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Text;
```